# Find all buttons with no text and replace with new text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several buttons like this:

```
<button class="my-btn" id="1"></button>
<button class="my-btn" id="2">100</button>
<button class="my-btn" id="3"></button>
<button class="my-btn" id="4">200</button>
<button class="my-btn" id="5"></button>
```

On page load I need to find all buttons with no text (number) and insert `0`. I have been trying several versions of this, but no luck:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.my-btn').text() == '') {
    $('.my-btn').text('0');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your current logic is that you're currently getting the `text()` from all `.my-btn` elements, hence `$('.my-btn').text()` is returning `100200` and does not match the `''` in the condition.

To fix this you need to loop over all the elements individually. You can do this with an implicit loop by providing a function to `text()` which checks what the current value is and returns what the updated value should be. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my-btn').text(function(i, t) {
    return t.trim() || '0';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="my-btn" id="1"></button>
<button class="my-btn" id="2">100</button>
<button class="my-btn" id="3"></button>
<button class="my-btn" id="4">200</button>
<button class="my-btn" id="5"></button>
```

*Update - 2020-03*:

Here's a shorter version using ES6 which will work in all modern browsers - basically anything except IE.

```
$('.my-btn').text((i, t) => t.trim() || '0');
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Your time is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through all of your buttons, I'm doing this with an each loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.my-btn').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == '') {
        $(this).text('0');
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="my-btn" id="1"></button>
<button class="my-btn" id="2">100</button>
<button class="my-btn" id="3"></button>
<button class="my-btn" id="4">200</button>
<button class="my-btn" id="5"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. For some reason, your version is not working for me, but I will try again and will double check my code. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: hmm it works if you click run code snippet. So it might be how you implemented it.

Comment: I think I may have some white space in there so perhaps if I would add the `trim()`. Thanks either way!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to check all the `<button>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    const $myBtns = $('.my-btn');
    $myBtns.each((i,btn) => {
      if($(btn).text() === '') $(btn).text('0')
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="my-btn" id="1"></button>
<button class="my-btn" id="2">100</button>
<button class="my-btn" id="3"></button>
<button class="my-btn" id="4">200</button>
<button class="my-btn" id="5"></button>
```